# Catch browser closing event in Android browser

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, dom-events

How do I catch the browser close or more specifically page unload event in Android browser? I couldn't make it work in the Android browser with the events like `unload`, `beforeunload` etc.

Comment: Are you talking this to handle by using Java programming or from mobile web?

Comment: WebViewClient may be helpful to you somewhat: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html

Comment: im talking about handling this event in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

```
    /* Tell the client to display a dialog to confirm navigation away from
 the current page. This is the result of the onbeforeunload javascript event.
 If the client returns true, WebView will assume that the client will handle
 the confirm dialog and call the appropriate JsResult method. If the client
 returns false, a default value of true will be returned to javascript to accept
 navigation away from the current page. The default behavior is to return false.
 Setting the JsResult to true will navigate away from the current page, false will
 cancel the navigation.
    */
        public boolean onJsBeforeUnload (WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result){

        }
```

from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html

I think you might also inject code into your web page displayed by WebView:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnBeforeUnLoad () {
        return "";
    }
</script>
```

using

```
@Override  
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
    {  
        webview.loadUrl("string with your script");  
    }
```